# Linq GroupBy to Class

Tags: c#, linq

So, i have the following classes:

```
public class Category
{
   public int idCategory { get; set; };
   public string nameCategory { get; set; };
   public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
   public int idProduct { get; set; };
   public string nameProduct { get; set; };
   public float price { get; set; };
}
```

i have a method that return a list that contains element on this way :

```
idCategory, nameCategory, idProduct, nameProduct, price
 0, Shoes, 0, Jordan, 99.9
 0, Shoes, 1, Nike, 59.9
 0, Shoes, 2, Adidas, 85.6
 0, Shoes, 3, NewFeel, 11.0
 1, watch, 6, Armani, 59.9
 1, watch, 8, CK, 85.6
 1, watch, 9, Rolex, 11.0
```

now i want to get them as a List of Catgory.

i can loop through this list to create a List of Father but what i want to do is to use the linq "group by" or any other methods to achieve this.

is this possible ?

Comment: Please be more descriptive on what you expect. Acutally give us some dummy data and what you expect. Thanks !

Comment: Since you have a series of objects in your list, 'GroupBy()' method only groups those objects and NOT the content of those objects.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make your method return a list<father>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
flatList
    .GroupBy(i => i.FatherId)
    .Select(g => new Father()
    {
        id = g.Key,
        propertyF,
        children =
            g
                .Select(c => new Child()
                {
                    id = ChildrenId,
                    prop1,
                    prop2
                })
                .ToList()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have trouble making that work with the list you provided, here's an alternative:

```
List<string> input = new List<string>
{
    "idCategory,nameCategory,idProduct,nameProduct,price",
    "0,Shoes,0,Jordan,99.9",
    "0,Shoes,1,Nike,59.9",
    "0,Shoes,2,Adidas,85.6",
    "0,Shoes,3,NewFeel,11.0",
    "1,watch,6,Armani,59.9",
    "1,watch,8,CK,85.6",
    "1,watch,9,Rolex,11.0",
};
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
foreach(string s in input.Skip(1))
{
    string[] temp = s.Split(',');
    if(categories.Contains<Category>(new Category
    {
        idCategory = int.Parse(temp[0])
    }, new CategoryEquality()))
        categories.Find(id => id.idCategory == int.Parse(temp[0])).products.Add(new Product
        {
            idProduct = int.Parse(temp[2]),
            nameProduct = temp[3],
            price = float.Parse(temp[4])
        });
    else
        categories.Add(new Category
        {
            idCategory = int.Parse(temp[0]),
            nameCategory = temp[1],
            products = new List<Product> 
            { new Product 
                { 
                    idProduct = int.Parse(temp[2]), 
                    nameProduct = temp[3], 
                    price = float.Parse(temp[4]) 
                } 
            }
        });
}
    public class CategoryEquality : IEqualityComparer<Category>
    {
        public bool Equals(Category a, Category b)
        {
            return a.idCategory == b.idCategory;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Category a)
        {
            return a.idCategory.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
    public class Category
    {
        public int idCategory
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string nameCategory
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public List<Product> products
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int idProduct
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string nameProduct
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public float price
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, i like your code it's simple and easy to understand, but i was looking for something like "D Stanley" Answer and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
fathers.SelectMany(f => f.children, 
                        (f, c) => new YourConsolidatedClassName 
                                  { 
                                      Id = f.Id, 
                                      propertyF = f.propertyF, 
                                      ChildId = c.Id, 
                                      prop1 = c.prop1, 
                                      prop2 = c.prop2 
                                  }).ToList();
```